# How draw 3D objects on gwt-openlayers map using ArcGis and KML? Or with any other approach?

Tags: gwt, 3d, kml, arcgis, gwt-openlayers

Is it possible to create `gwt-openlayers` map with 3D objects on it?

I know that 
[KML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyhole_Markup_Language) layers can be used for drawing 3D objects and [supported by](http://demo.gwt-openlayers.org/gwt_ol_showcase/GwtOpenLayersShowcase.html?example=KML%20example) `gwt-openlayers`. And I also know that `gwt-openlayers` [can draw WMS and WFS layers](http://demo.gwt-openlayers.org/gwt_ol_showcase/GwtOpenLayersShowcase.html?example=WMS%20with%20WFS%20overlay) from remote ArcGis web-service.

Questions:

1. In the KML example I mentioned above some local static .kml file used. I need to show moving 3D objects on the map. Is it possible to deploy KML web service on arcgis which takes coordinates as locates 3D models to taken coordinates?
2. Is there any working example of using KML in gwt-openlayers **from web-service but not from local file**?  If I replace `protocolOptions.setUrl("lines.kml")` in the example to  `protocolOptions.setUrl("http:web-service-url")` will it work?
3. Is there any online KML services which I can use to check my app?

Answer (score 0):

1. No idea
2. According to me this should work. Have you tried this ?
3. No idea

Comment: No, I haven't because now I don't now how to deploy KML based web service. I'm going to find online service, test my code and only after successful test stay on KML.